# Doubts about the general solution of $y'' +7y' = e^{-7x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some doubts about how to find the general integral of this ODE:

$$y'' +7y' = e^{-7x}$$

I know that first we find the solution to the homogeneous ODE and then the particular solution. When I was solving the homogeneous  I got to:

$$y_h= K_1 e^0 + K_2 e^{-7x}$$

My doubt is that is it correct to put $y_h= K_1 + K_2 e^{-7x}$? Or is the $e^0$ some kind of special case I need to know and do something else. Also, to find the particular solution I'm doing

$$ y_p = A+Be^{-7x}$$

and then doing the substitutions and equalling them to the LHS of the original ODE.

Thanks.

Comment: Your particular solution will not be of the same form as the homogeneous solution. If you apply the differential operator $y\mapsto y''+7y'$ to any of the homogeneous solutions you get $0$, whereas when you apply it to a particular solution you get $e^{-7x}$, therefore the particular solution is not among the homogeneous solution.

Comment: You are correct that the $e^0$ is strange. If one wants to emphasize that the constant term is an exponential term with exponential factor $0$, then one should write it as such, $e^{0x}$. This is important in its connection to the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
y'' + 7y' = e^{-7x} \Longleftrightarrow y' + 7y = -\frac{e^{-7x}}{7} + k \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{7x})' = -\frac{1}{7} + ke^{7x}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2):

For the particular solution, note the r.h.s. is one of the basic solutions of the homogeneous equation, so we  search for a particular solution of the form
$$y(x)=Cx\mathrm e^{-7x}.$$

Comment: I was searching a little bit more about your method. I noted that the $x$ that multiplies the exponential can be of a certain degree depending on if the r.h.s. has or not one of the basic solutions. How can one determine the degree of this $x$?

Comment: This depends on the multiplicity of the coefficient in the exponential as a root of the characteristic equation: if it is not a root, you have a multiple of the exponential in the r.h.s. If it is a simple root, you multiply the former by $x$. If it is a double root, by $x^2$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

$$y'' +7y' = e^{-7x}$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(y' e^{7x})'=1$$
And integrate.

Answer (score 0):

I take $y'=p$. The equation becomes
$$p'+7p=e^{-7 x}$$
which gives the solution
$$p=y'=c_1 e^{-7 x}+e^{-7 x} x$$
Integrating again
$$y= -\frac{1}{49} e^{-7 x} ( c_1+7 x)+c_2$$

Comment: How did $7y'$ become $p$ in the equation?